# r shiny: dynamically program legend position

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app, a stacked bar plot is produced. The number of columns is variable and depends on the user's input. When there are few columns, the legend is displayed properly:

[image]

However, when the number of columns is high, the legend overlaps the graph:

[image]

Could you please give me a hint how I could dynamically program the position of the legend so that it would always be 1. visible; 2. not overlapping with the graph? Thanks!

Here is the code for the graph:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,2,14)+1,xpd=TRUE,ps=14,cex.main=1.143,cex.lab=1.143,font.lab=2)
barplot(rbind(plotdffeedingh$apercentvector,plotdffeedingh$bpercentvector,plotdffeedingh$cpercentvector,plotdffeedingh$dpercentvector,plotdffeedingh$epercentvector,plotdffeedingh$fpercentvector),
        main="Feeding type composition of the herbivore nematode assemblage", xlim=c(0,length(plotdffeedingh$leveltreats)+2), 
        xlab="",ylab="Fraction, % of herbivore nematodes", names.arg=levels(plotdffeedingh$leveltreats), 
        legend.text=c("Sedentary parasites","Migratory endoparasites","Semi-endoparasites","Ectoparasites","Epidermal/root hair feeders","Algal/lichen/moss feeders"), 
        args.legend=list(x="right",inset=c(-0.2,0)),col=c("blue","yellow","red","grey","green","brown"),las=2)
```